# C++, error: expected class-name before '{' token

Tags: c++, class, dependencies, codeblocks

I have cloned an open source code from [github](https://github.com/robotology-dependencies/qpOASES). This project is to be compiled with make which is totally fine. I reconfigured it and created a codeblocks project added its files. I also misplaced some of the files and I did some fixes as well.

My problem is when I compile it, I face with so many errors and the first one is:

```
error: expected class-name before '{' token
```

in `QProblem.hpp`:

```
#include <qpOASES/QProblemB.hpp>
#include <qpOASES/Constraints.hpp>
#include <qpOASES/ConstraintProduct.hpp>
#include <qpOASES/Matrices.hpp>


BEGIN_NAMESPACE_QPOASES

class QProblem : public QProblemB // error is here
{
```

while `QProblemB` has been defined in `QProblemB.hpp` which is included:

QProblemB.hpp:

```
#include <qpOASES/Flipper.hpp>
#include <qpOASES/Options.hpp>
#include <qpOASES/Matrices.hpp>


BEGIN_NAMESPACE_QPOASES


class SolutionAnalysis;

class QProblemB
{
    friend class SolutionAnalysis;

    public:
        QProblemB( );
```

I tried adding

```
class QProblemB;
```

However this idea did not work. It leads to another error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class qpOASES::QProblemB'
```

I could not simplify the source code further. So I uploaded the full project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fdv24dg2ofgl7b/test02.zip?dl=1). The codeblocks project file is inside a folder called `codeblocks`.

---

**UPDATE**

I realized by updating all the files and adding `#pragma once` in all of them and changing all `cpp` files to `hpp` except for the main cpp file, the problem will be fixed. I am still wondering what has been the problem.

Comment: most probably some of you hpp files were being loaded twice